# keep track of the position of a div in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, draggable

I have a textarea that keeps track of a moveble div like this

```
    $('#content').children().draggable({ 
        drag : function () {
                $('#textarea').text("left:" +($(this).position().left) + "px" + "\ntop:" + $(this).position().top + "px");
        } 
    });
```

The problem is that if i write something in that textarea, it will stop updating the position if i move the div.
If the text in the textarea is like this:

blablablabla
left:10px
top:20px;
blablablablabla

I want to be able to write in the textarea and update the position if i move the div without the other content of the textarea being removed.

someone should be able write whatever they want in the textarea and if they move it, the position will appear a specific place or at the end of what they have written

Any ideas?

Example using ".val" instead of ".text": http://jsfiddle.net/Ydkrw/
".val" will remove the existing text...

Update: based on valentinos answer i did like so: http://jsfiddle.net/8G82U/
But this doesn't work if you write something in the textarea before you move it

Comment: Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net to see your problem in action?

Comment: Could you save the string saying, e.g, "left:10px top:20px" in a variable, and do a string replace on it when the div is moved?

Comment: wouldn't it be hard replacing the position numbers when they change all the time? I don't know what i should replace the the new position with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be something to get you started. This is just a rough design that might help you. Used `substring` and `replace` javascript methods.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ydkrw/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the string denoting the position in variable, and replace only that string when you drag the div. Like this:

```
var position;
var oldposition = '';

$('#content').children().draggable({
    drag: function () {       
        position = "left:" + ($(this).position().left) + "px" + "\ntop:" +     $(this).position().top + "px";
        $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val().replace(oldposition, position));   
        oldposition = position;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCT9f/

Comment: This is clever, but only works until you manually change the position values from the textarea.

Comment: Thanks, but as roydukkey said, it will stop working if you mess with the numbers. Maybe you could answer this to? If i write something in the textarea before i move it, it will post the position in the beginning. Is it possible to post this in a specific place and/or last in the textarea?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/kCT9f/1 also re-appends if someone messes with the numbers. This one appends it to the end and then replaces it in situ thereafter - http://jsfiddle.net/kCT9f/2/  - but doesn't help with number-messing situation. You could compare the text to see if messing has occured and re-append though.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I'm doing something like this I add a replacement keys to the content and replace it when I need to prepare the content.

```
<textarea>blablablabla {left: 10px} {top: 20px} blablablablabla</textarea>
```

Update the keywords when the div is moved like this.

```
$('#content').children().draggable({ 
    drag: function(){
        var text = $('#textarea').text();

        // Replace Keys
        text = replaceLengthKey(text, "left", $(this).position().left);
        text = replaceLengthKey(text, "top", $(this).position().top);

        // Return changes
        $("#textarea").text(text);
    } 
});

function replaceLengthKey(source, name, value){
    // Absolute length units: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units
    return source.replace(RegExp("\\{" + name + ":\\s*[0-9]*(px|mm|cm|in|pt|pc)?\\}", "gm"), "{" + name + ": " + value + "}")
}
```

Then, when you prepare the content as you want on the server or client, but at least the structure will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the position text within brackets and then when the div is moved apply a regular expression and change only the text within the brackets. Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ydkrw/15/).

```
 var text=$('#textarea').val();
 var newPos = "(left:" + ($(this).position().left) + "px" + "\ntop:" +($(this).position().top) + "px)"
 text=text.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, newPos);
 $('#textarea').val(text);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that u have to have those brackets, someone should be able write whatever they want in the textarea and if they move it, the position will appear a specific place or at the end of what they have written

Comment: Is it possible to create those brackets with javascript when the textarea is being moved and then replace them with the position?